# What does it mean to patch cables or devices together?

Tags: meaning, etymology, american-english

In the below context:

> Finally had the time over the weekend to patch everything down and sort out the sockets.
>
> ...
>
> I managed to get my trusty router patched in with the phone line coming from the hallway to the cab via the CAT6 cable.

What does the term patched mean, and what is its origin? It's clearly AmEng, but as a Brit I can't be sure whether it simply means patching in the normal IT sense of connecting two systems together, or whether it has a more nuanced definition that has temporary connotations.

Comment: I do not believe there is any nuance or ambiguity involved here. "Patch" here  means to join or connect.

Comment: It's an incorrect use of the word: *to patch* means to connect **temporarily**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an IT professional, I've been using patch cables (cords) to patch between routers, switches, phone equipment, and the like for decades. This use of patch is found in the definition 4a, below. I've also applied patches to misbehaving software, and patched people in on conference calls. When I worked on [Buchla](https://buchla.com) synthesisers, I used [patch cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#Patch) to connect hardware modules together. The term has lasted into the digital age.

> **[patch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patch)** - verb
>
> patched; patching; patches
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1 : to mend, cover, or fill up a hole or weak spot in
>
> 2 : to provide with a patch
>
> 3a : to make of patches or fragments
>
> b: to mend or put together especially in hasty or shabby fashion
>   —usually used with up
>
> c : to apply a patch to (a computer program)
>
> **4a : to connect (things, such as circuits) by a patch cord**
>
> b : to connect (a person, a message, etc.) to a communication system
>   especially temporarily
>
> *they patched him into the conference call*

From: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patch)

Comment: So it has the specific meaning of connecting patch cables? I've heard the term patch cables but never knew exactly what it meant, I'm guessing that's mostly an AmEng thing that usually means RJ-45/ethernet.

Comment: Ethernet and more! I was patching cables long before RJ45 cabling existed. Nowadays, patching usually refers to ethernet cabling.

Comment: "Patch cable" is any sort of relatively short cable that might be used to connect pieces of equipment together.

Comment: The term comes from old telephone equipment, but apparently not back to its inception. Here's an early snippet from *Telephony*, 1932. https://books.google.com/books?id=IfbmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22patch+cord%22&dq=%22patch+cord%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfvNeitYDgAhUBPa0KHReYClYQ6AEIQTAF

Comment: @Hashim Have you never seen an old film where the telephone operator says to a caller "Just a moment, I'll patch you through"? https://photovault.com/344887

Comment: @michael.hor257k To patch something has a lot of definitions. I was aware of all of them except 4a outlined in this answer, likely because it's more of an Americanism, and it's not immediately clear from it alone that its etymology comes from the telephone definition.

Comment: @Hashim It's not just an AmE term. It's very widely used in the UK as well, in particular the panels used to connect routers to installed cables are called "patch panels".

Comment: @BoldBen The use of "patch cable"/"patch cord"? Not at all. I'm from Sheffield, so maybe it's either a Southern thing or a generational thing.

Comment: @Hashim I'm from Derbyshire originally and did my IT work in Yorkshire and Lincolnshire. I've no idea how you've managed to miss "patching in" unless it's generational: I'm retired.

Comment: @BoldBen I never said anything about not knowing the term "patching in". I specifically said that definition 4a - a "patch cord" or "patch cable" - was the term I was unfamiliar with and that sounded like an Americanism to me.

Comment: @hashim Patching in has always been done with patch cables in my experience. I admit that Americans seem to use the term 'patch cable' for the cable connecting a device to a network point where I would say 'network cable' or 'drop lead' but since the shorter ones are physically indistinguishable from patch cables and, in fact, could be used as patch leads in a cabinet I don't have a problem with it.